# Load 3D model with HTML5 canvas element and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, model-view

I have a simple concept that I want to use HTML5 for, but I'm a total newbie when it comes to canvas and model viewers written in Javascript.  I have a 3D model of a desk lamp and I'd like only the head part of the lamp to rotate with mouse movement. This [CSS3 box shadow effect](http://www.zachstronaut.com/lab/text-shadow-box/text-shadow-box.html) is sort of what I mean, but I already have the 3D model drawn out in Maya that I'd like to load with HTML5 and use Javascript for cursor interaction. I only need the head part of the lamp to retain 3D attributes, I can use a png for the base.  I hope this makes sense, I would normally just use flash,  but I'd like to do this with HTML5 if possible.

Comment: check out [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/)

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I need, maybe someone could shed some light on how to load a JSON model with three.js? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am new to webgl too, you can do it with three.js. If you are using Blender there is a converter script available which will convert the model to json file.

Then u can load the json file on canvas using json loader of three.js. I found these links useful to load json model. Hope it helps

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/porting-3d-graphics-to-the-web-webgl-intro-part-2/

check out the source of this example - http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_materials_reflection.html

Answer (score 1):

CSS 3 won't help you with that, sounds like you'll need to use WebGL which is a *"JavaScript API for rendering interactive 3D graphics within any compatible web browser without the use of plug-ins"*

Try the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) and the [official site](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/) (there's also the "[test if your browser supports WebGL site](http://get.webgl.org/)")

Comment: On the contrary... I have a 3D CSS engine I'm planning on open sourcing soon.  Not that it helps the OP, I just found your comment surprisingly relevant :)

Comment: A 3D CSS engine capable of what? Modelling 3D objects?

Comment: Yep.  Straight from .obj and .mtl files.  And animating them using CSS3 transitions, specular mapping, flat shading, phong shading at 0.1 fps ;)

Comment: Ok so it looks like in order to use my model, I have to convert it from dwg(autocad) to dae(collada), encode as JSON then load with AJAX into an HTML5 canvas.  Then I'm hoping to map the JSON model to follow mouse movement.  Does anyone know of good related references with examples?

Answer (score 0):

Try jsc3d at : https://code.google.com/p/jsc3d/

Quoted : 
..JSC3D is built on pure Javascript software rendering using 2d canvas technology as well as an optional WebGL back-end that provides more efficient rendering...